# Switch Databases dynamically

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I'm doing a POS(point of sale) as Saas with React in the frontend, NodeJs in backend(API Rest) and MongoDB as the database.

I've finished a basic program and now I want any user is registered will have his own database.

After read some articles and question on the internet my conclusion was switch between databases each time the frontend consume the backend(API).

**General Logic:**

1. User Log in
2. In the backend, I use a general database to check user credentials and also I acquire the name of the database of this user.
3. Each time the frontend consumes the API the next codes are executed in a middleware to know what database should use the API:

```js
var dbUser = db.useDb('nameDataBaseUser');
var Product = dbUser.model('Product', ProductSquema);
```

I have the schemas and the variable 'db' defined fixed in the code:

`var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost');`

**Problem:**

I don't know if is the correct solution about what I am trying to make, but it seems me inefficient that the model is generated constantly each time the API is called, because in some API(i.e in some middlewares I have until 4 different models)

**Question:**

This is the best way? or any suggestion to face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the idea of creating a new db for each new user. That seems to create a lot of complexity and makes it difficult to maintain, and makes it difficult to access the data for analytics and such later. Why not use a new collection per new user? That way you can use just one set of db access credentials. Furthermore, [Creating a new collection happens](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/databases-and-collections/#collections) automatically when you store data for it.